# User Input validation in bot framework composer with costum fonction from list not allowed

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have an "ask question" with a herocard as prompt for text with buttons generated from an imported json file using a function wrote with language generation

[Herocard

```
 title = Country Selection
subtitle = Signature rules
text = What is your Country ?
buttons = ${foreach(GetSignatureData(), item, cardActionTemplate('imBack', item['value']['value'], item.key))}
```

the function looks like this :

> #GetSignatureData()
> ${json(fromFile('./dataSignature.json'))}

The result is stored in dialog.country

I want to allow the user to choose only what proposed in the buttons generated from the heroCard (i'm traversing a json file using keys proposed in the herocard). For that i want to use a Validation rules, but i'm not allowed to put costum fucntion other then what proposed in [Adaptive expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-concept-adaptive-expressions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=arithmetic)

[image]

When trying to to put a validation rule like this one :

> ${contains((createArray(foreach(GetSignatureData(), item, item.key))), this.value)}

i have this error message :

> GetSignatureData() it’s not a built-in function or a custom function.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution or do you still need assistance? There have been a few releases since your post that may have corrected this already, if you haven't upgraded, yet.